# failed to connect derby database from two processes simultaneously

Tags: derby

In Websphere Application Server, I have a derby database which is used in the application PlantsByWebSphere.ear.   I started the WAS server and the application, the application works well,  which means the database works well.

I wanted to monitor the data in the database, so I used Rational Application Developer(or Eclipse) to connect the database, but it failed with behind error message. However, if I shutdown the started WAS Server, the database becomes connectable. Does Derby allow more than one process (i.e WAS and RAD/Eclipse) to connect to the database simultaneously? If not allow, is there any convenient way to monitor the data in database when the application is running?

> Could not connect to PLANTSDB.
>   Error creating SQL Model Connection
>   connection to PLANTSDB. (Error: Failed to start database
>   'C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile2\installedApps\acerwinNode05Cell\PlantsByWebSphere.ear\Database\PLANTSDB',
>   see the next exception for details.)   Failed to start database
>   'C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile2\installedApps\acerwinNode05Cell\PlantsByWebSphere.ear\Database\PLANTSDB',
>   see the next exception for details.
>   Error creating JDBC Connection
>   connection to PLANTSDB. (Error: Failed to start database
>   'C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile2\installedApps\acerwinNode05Cell\PlantsByWebSphere.ear\Database\PLANTSDB',
>   see the next exception for details.)   Failed to start database
>   'C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile2\installedApps\acerwinNode05Cell\PlantsByWebSphere.ear\Database\PLANTSDB',
>   see the next exception for details.

Answer (score 0):

First, an aside: when your exception says "see the next exception for details," do this: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Now regarding your larger question: indeed, you may not connect to the same Derby database using the Derby Embedded Engine from two different processes simultaneously.

To understand this in more detail, spend some time reading this: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/devguide/cdevdvlp27610.html and also this: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/devguide/cdevdvlp20458.html#cdevdvlp20458

You can deploy Derby in the client-server configuration, in which case there is a single Derby Network Server, and applications all connect to it using a network connection (and a slightly different JDBC driver in your classpath).

To understand more about the Derby Network Server configuration, start here: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

And it probably wouldn't hurt to take an hour or two and work through this on your system: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Now I understand that I can not connect to the database from WAS and RAD/Eclipse at the same time because Derby works in embedded environment in my case.